Block script requests within an iFrame using Manifestv3
I’m currently migrating a browser extension from Manifest v2 to Manifest v3. Among other things, the extension creates an iFrame of the currently open page, but it blocks a specific script within the iFrame.
I was able to achieve this well in v2 by using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener and checking if details.url.includes("abcd.js") && details.frameId !== 0 was true, and then blocking the request if the condition was met.
In Manifest v3, I need to somehow transfer this to declarative_net_request, but I can’t find a way that worked :(
Does anyone have an idea or even a solution?

There's no alternative for within the iFrame condition and you should complain about it in https://crbug.com and WECG, because chromium team blithely thinks they did a good job replacing webRequest with DNR. A limited workaround might be possible if the iframe's URL is known and unique, in which case you can specify it in initiatorDomains.

It seems like 'initiatorDomains' can only match hostnames ... if it could also recognize parameters, I would be able to solve my problem with it. Since I create the iFrame myself, I can add a unique parameter. I'll give it a try, but I don't really have much hope after reading the documentation.
